# Extract Values From Cells Based On Corresponding Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to extract values from preceding rows based on a value which is given in next columns.

Like in following example (Explanation Table Image), in cell A2 Cell value is 10 (Highlighted in Green) the corresponding value in cell D2 is 3 (Highlighted in Red) so the value required in Cell E2, E3 & E4 is values of cells A3, A4 and A5 which are A-1111, B-2222, C-3333 after removing text "SLR# " respectively. And in case of Cell A6 the corresponding value in cell D6 is 2 so the required value in cell E6 & E7 will be D-4444 & E-5555.

The data continuous like this and formula or VBA code will fill my requirement in column E. Kindly let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks in advance...

Explanation Table:

[image]

I have tried the following User Defined Function but it gives me all values in one cell rather in next cell. (Thanks to Mr. Fluff for this UDF)

```
Function UDF(Rng As Range, Rws As Long) As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Cl As Range

   For Each Cl In Rng
      If Left(Cl, 4) = "SLR#" Then
         UDf = UDF & Cl.Value
         i = i + 1
         If i = Rws Then Exit For
      End If
   Next Cl
   UDF = Trim(Replace(fiberboysa, "SLR#", ""))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be simplifying this but if the data is **ALWAYS** structured that way then try this formula ...

```
=IF(D3<>"","",IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",A3))
```

... copy that into cell **E2** and fill down.

[image]

I'm happy if it doesn't do it for you but it worked with the simple example you gave.

Comment: Its working for only one time. Like if there is 3 in column D it will only bring one value from column A but i need 3 proceeding values in column E.

Comment: @Accounts-Loves-Code, and you filled the formula down?  If it's only working once then I assume you never filled it down.  I updated my answer with a screenshot showing it working.  If that isn't doing it for you then I'm clearly missing something.  I'd need to see the result you're talking about when you apply mt answer.

Comment: Yup!!! Done it. Actually my data is very big so I added some more IFs that is why it was not working. I fixed it and its working now. Thanks again dear!!!